# gRPC/proto Google cloud client libraries vs GAPIC Google cloud client libraries

Tags: python, google-api, google-cloud-platform, grpc

I've mostly found working with google's client libraries easy to work with, intuitive, and well suited to idiomatic python, with the notable exception of auth (there is a special place in hell for whoever came up with the oAuth dance)  Although in the past, most of my work was on Gsuite, I'm tinkering with the google cloud client libraries,

Looking for a specific library i realised they come in two flavors now: gRPC and GAPIC. although both come with a side of pickles, I could not find any reference about which flavor would be preferable to the other, (if any).

### Gapic Flavor

```
(ame) hector@trantor ~/a/envs ❯❯❯ pip search gapic
gapic-google-iam-admin-v1 (0.10.0)                     - GAPIC library for the Google IAM Admin API
gapic-google-cloud-spanner-admin-instance-v1 (0.15.3)  - GAPIC library for the Cloud Spanner Instance Admin API
gapic-google-cloud-spanner-admin-database-v1 (0.15.3)  - GAPIC library for the Cloud Spanner Database Admin API
gapic-google-cloud-speech-v1 (0.15.3)                  - GAPIC library for the Google Cloud Speech API
gapic-google-cloud-language-v1beta2 (0.15.3)           - GAPIC library for the Google Cloud Natural Language API
google-cloud-trace (0.15.5)                            - GAPIC library for the Stackdriver Trace API
gapic-google-cloud-functions-v1beta2 (0.15.3)          - GAPIC library for the Google Cloud Functions API
gapic-google-cloud-spanner-v1 (0.15.3)                 - GAPIC library for the Cloud Spanner API
gapic-google-cloud-language-v1 (0.15.3)                - GAPIC library for the Google Cloud Natural Language API
gapic-google-cloud-monitoring-v3 (0.15.3)              - GAPIC library for the Stackdriver Monitoring API
gapic-google-cloud-error-reporting-v1beta1 (0.15.3)    - GAPIC library for the Stackdriver Error Reporting API
gapic-google-cloud-pubsub-v1 (0.15.4)                  - GAPIC library for the Google Cloud Pub/Sub API
gapic-google-cloud-language-v1beta1 (0.11.1)           - GAPIC library for the Google Language API
gapic-google-cloud-logging-v2 (0.91.3)                 - GAPIC library for the Stackdriver Logging API
gapic-google-cloud-datastore-v1 (0.90.4)               - GAPIC library for the Google Cloud Datastore API
gapic-google-cloud-speech-v1beta1 (0.15.3)             - GAPIC library for the Google Cloud Speech API
gapic-google-cloud-vision-v1 (0.90.3)                  - GAPIC library for the Google Cloud Vision API
gapic-google-monitoring-v3 (0.11.1)                    - GAPIC library for the Stackdriver Monitoring API
gapic-google-longrunning (0.11.2)                      - GAPIC library for the Google Google API
gapic-google-maps-streetview_publish-v1 (0.1.4)        - GAPIC library for the Street View Publish API
gapic-google-pubsub-v1 (0.11.1)                        - GAPIC library for the Google Pubsub API
```

#### gRPC/protocol flavor:

```
(ame) hector@trantor ~/a/envs ❯❯❯ pip search grpc | grep google                                        I
grpc-google-iam-admin-v1 (0.10.0)                      - GRPC library for the google-iam-admin-v1 service
proto-google-cloud-spanner-admin-database-v1 (0.15.3)  - GRPC library for the Cloud Spanner Database Admin API
proto-google-cloud-spanner-admin-instance-v1 (0.15.3)  - GRPC library for the Cloud Spanner Instance Admin API
google-assistant-grpc (0.0.2)                          - Google Assistant API gRPC bindings
proto-google-cloud-language-v1beta2 (0.15.3)           - GRPC library for the Google Cloud Natural Language API
grpc-google-cloud-pubsub-v1 (0.14.0)                   - GRPC library for the Google Pubsub service
grpc-google-cloud-monitoring-v3 (0.14.0)               - GRPC library for the Stackdriver Monitoring API service
proto-google-cloud-speech-v1 (0.15.3)                  - GRPC library for the Google Cloud Speech API
grpc-google-cloud-language-v1 (0.14.0)                 - GRPC library for the Google Language service
grpc-google-cloud-error-reporting-v1beta1 (0.14.0)     - GRPC library for the Stackdriver Error Reporting API
proto-google-cloud-logging-v2 (0.91.3)                 - GRPC library for the Stackdriver Logging API
grpc-google-cloud-logging-v2 (0.90.0)                  - GRPC library for the Stackdriver Logging service
proto-google-cloud-functions-v1beta2 (0.15.3)          - GRPC library for the Google Cloud Functions API
grpc-google-cloud-datastore-v1 (0.14.0)                - GRPC library for the Google Datastore service
grpc-google-cloud-speech-v1beta1 (0.14.0)              - GRPC library for the Google Speech service
proto-google-cloud-spanner-v1 (0.15.3)                 - GRPC library for the Cloud Spanner API
proto-google-cloud-speech-v1beta1 (0.15.3)             - GRPC library for the Google Cloud Speech API
proto-google-cloud-monitoring-v3 (0.15.3)              - GRPC library for the Stackdriver Monitoring API
proto-google-cloud-language-v1 (0.15.3)                - GRPC library for the Google Cloud Natural Language API
proto-google-cloud-error-reporting-v1beta1 (0.15.3)    - GRPC library for the Stackdriver Error Reporting API
proto-google-cloud-vision-v1 (0.90.3)                  - GRPC library for the Google Cloud Vision API
proto-google-cloud-datastore-v1 (0.90.4)               - GRPC library for the Google Cloud Datastore API
proto-google-cloud-pubsub-v1 (0.15.4)                  - GRPC library for the Google Cloud Pub/Sub API
grpc-google-cloud-vision-v1 (0.14.0)                   - GRPC library for the Google Cloud Vision API service
grpc-google-cloud-language-v1beta1 (0.11.1)            - GRPC library for the google-cloud-language-v1beta1 service
grpc-google-monitoring-v3 (0.11.1)                     - GRPC library for the google-monitoring-v3 service
grpc-google-longrunning-v2 (0.8.1)                     - GRPC library for the google-longrunning-v2 service
proto-google-maps-streetview_publish-v1 (0.1.4)        - GRPC library for the Street View Publish API
grpc-google-iam-v1 (0.11.4)                            - GRPC library for the google-iam-v1 service
grpc-google-pubsub-v1 (0.11.1)                         - GRPC library for the google-pubsub-v1 service`
```

To make maters more confusing , most libraries exist at the same revision number in both flavors with an older gRPC version around:

```
google-cloud-datastore-v1 (0.14.0)                - GRPC library for the Google Datastore service
google-cloud-datastore-v1 (0.90.4)               - GAPIC library for the Google Cloud Datastore API
google-cloud-datastore-v1 (0.90.4)               - GRPC library for the Google Cloud Datastore API
```

and

```
google-cloud-logging-v2 (0.90.0)                  - GRPC library for the Stackdriver Logging service
google-cloud-logging-v2 (0.91.3)                 - GAPIC library for the Stackdriver Logging API
google-cloud-logging-v2 (0.91.3)                 - GRPC library for the Stackdriver Logging API
```

also, the`assistant` API client comes only in gRPC `cloud-trace` is the opposite.

which client library should I choose to develop my app? is there any material difference either in idiomatic features or performance-wise? (i'd expect the gRPC libs to render a client more performant, but this is the internet and we're not all on reliable bandwidth) so, the trivial case of "*YMMV*" and "*choose the tool that will do the job*" are assumed.

documentation does not specify anything to the effect of which kind to choose, specially when both flavors are at the same version label.

Your insights are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really do not ever want or need to install a library with `gapic-`, `proto-`, or `grpc-` at the front of it. At one point, the libraries that you actually want were using these as dependencies. (We have moved away from that behavior, but for historical reasons we are stuck with those packages living on PyPI forever, most likely.)

The libraries you actually want to install are spelled `google-cloud-{api}` (e.g. `google-cloud-speech`, `google-cloud-pubsub`, etc.). In a small number of cases, these *may* pull in libraries with the prefixes you observed, although almost all if not all of them should be rid of those by now.

If you have any more questions, feel free to ask on our [issue tracker](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/).

Comment: Thank you! I figured at some point that all these are dependencies of larger packages, but still wondered as to the impact on the dependent app, performancewise, or advantages to the developer, as in the use of more idiomatic APIs in favor of convoluted nonsensical constructs that sometimes come with generated code. I was just wondering now, the `gdata-` flavor seems to have gone the way of the dodo on PyPi, so maybe the same fate awaits `proto-` `gapic-` et al?